# Why not list the 7 Minim in order with no second "Eretz"?

Tags: words, tractate-brachot, ekev

Devarim 8:8 ארץ חיטה ושעורה, וגפן ותאנה ורימון; ארץ-זית שמן, ודבש. The Gemara in [Berachos 41:](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14308&st=&pgnum=87) says in the name of either Rabbi Yosef or Rabbi Yitzchok that the order of the Brachos would depend on what is written closer to Eretz.

Based on this if one would have Grapes, Figs, Pomegranates, Olives and Dates one would make the Bracha on the Olive since Olives are closer to the word Eretz.

Why is there a need for the second Eretz in this verse? Why could the verse not be set up as follows? ארץ חיטה וזית שמן ושעורה ודבש וגפן ותאנה ורימון and leave out the seemingly extra Eretz?

Comment: I'm not sure how the first two paragraphs support the question, other than perhaps as an answer to it - "To teach us this halacha." In other words, the actual question reads like more of a [tag:parshanut-torah-comment] question than a [tag:masechet-berachot] question.

Comment: Zayit shemen and dvash are products of fruits, not fruits themselves.  And they are the only liquids.

Comment: what about the eretz's in the next Pasuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meshech Chachmah answers that shemen zayis and devash are exclusive to Ertez Yisroel and you can see this from when klal Yisrael said why are you taking us out of Eygpt which has grapes ,figs,pomegranates but no mention of olive oil and honey.They are connected to Eretz because they are special to Eretz Yisrael.